Proper termination of a Breadboard Bus
Aging software engineer here — about to embark on a labor-of-love hobby project that I have wanted to do for several decades.
Like so many before me, I plan to build a homebrew CPU, from SSI TTL. Nothing more complex than a 74LS181 allowed. To answer the obvious question, I will use 74LS series because I have many hundreds of them to hand.
The architecture I have chosen is per Tenenbaum, here is a picture;

I will simplify somewhat, fewer registers — I plan to implement a 6502 ISA.
The initial build will be on breadboard, like this:

I am familiar enough with hardware at a certain level, I do a lot of embedded firmware. But someone else has always built the PCBs.
The design works by enabling a register (a 74ls273, and a 74LS244 driver) onto the bus which feeds the ALU, during the low phase of the clock. After everything has settled, the rising clock edge latches the ALU output (again driven through a 74LS244) back (via the C bus on my breadboard) into another (or even the same) register.
Now my question. I'm totally new to transmission line theory, but I have been reading up about ringing, and bus termination.
I plan to add 1K pulldown resistors to the top (start) of the busses, since I want the input to the ALU, and indeed any output, to default to 0. I presume this will count as an OK start of bus termination.
What do I need to add to the bottom of the buses? Another 1K? It will be about 13 inches of breadboard (33 cm, as we like to say where I live.) Or is this even an issue I need to worry about, since the clock speed for this will probably be below 1 MHz ?

That's really huge breadboard. I see those used less and less, by students mainly. Are you sure you want to go this way? I have a lot if experience with rf and high frequency, but zero with using breadboards for 1MHz signal. I would guess you are fine using non-terminated lines. What i would suggest is twisting them with gnd. Good luck with that huge breadboard:)

Yep it's huge. Well it's a collection of smaller ones. Plan is to have flexibility to experiment, at very low speeds, (Single step up to 1KHz or so) using the breadboards. Then move to wirewrap, just because I'm a sadist.

@Voltage Spike Hello and thanks for the edit. I see that you changed "Labour" to "Labor" - is it a standard to use American Spelling only on posts?

You are using LS TTL chips.
They have such input and output characteristics that they should not be terminated with a pull-down, but rather a pull-up. The output high state is very weak to source current but output low state much stronger to sink current. Also the inputs source current out when pulled low more than when inputs are high.
If you need stronger termination or pull-ups than 1k, then it may be beneficial to terminate with a split termination of 220 ohms to 5V and 330 ohms to ground.
The frequency is actually not that relevant but the chips are capable to around 30 MHz operation and slew rate is about 6ns. In 6ns, light travels 1.8 meters, on PCB wires maybe 1.2 meters. Applying some rules of thumb, 12cm wiring should not need termination, and quarter wave is about 30cm, so if you are careful, 33 cm should not be a problem.
However breadboards are terrible platforms for high speed signals - fortunately LS chips are not hopeless to get working on breadboards, but any faster logic than LS may be difficult.
You still likely need proper supply and ground floorplans with 100nF bypass cap at each chip.

"they should not be terminated with a pull-down" - ouch, I did not know that. So, if I want un-driven lines to my 16 bit ALU to be zero, e.g. the upper 8 bits, how do I achieve this?

I read a detailed tutorial that calculated the pulldown resistor needed for a LS series chip here: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/pull-up-resistor.html

The first solution is to drive them low actively, or tie them to GND if you need them permanently unused.

Can't do either of those. I'm talking about the 16 inputs to one side of the ALU. So definitely can't ground them, they are always in use. But sometimes they will be driven by the output of a register, and sometimes there will be no register driving them, so I want them to be low - so the ALU sees 0.

Note that pin and breadboard stray capacitances limit rise time as well, and also reduce the effective velocity of connections (and make more opportunity for ringing, crosstalk and other misbehavior). 12cm may sound like a lot, but span a couple of those boards with zig-zagging buses and you'll find it adds up quickly!

@Greycon Pull-downs aren't bad per se, just suboptimal; TTL will happily drive a 1k pull-down while meeting logic thresholds (it might be a bit marginal in the minimum case, though). If lower resistance (faster settling) is required, I would consider a split divider, set to 0.5-0.8V say; or bus drivers and a proper matched-impedance bus. Alternately, anywhere you can arrange to use default-high levels, you get some synergy with the TTL input pin's output current as well.

Thanks @TimWilliams - I'll go read about such things as split dividers, etc. I will also see whether the ALU can operate in inverted logic, or I guess I could add invertors in front of the ALU inputs - so I can use pullups on the bus. So mych to learn :-) I really only want to prove out the hardware architecture here, so happy if it all runs at a few KHz.

@Greycon There should be some lessons learned from the original 6502 design, if you've been looking at the reverse-engineering of it as I imagine you might -- NMOS logic is similar in some respects to TTL. The main difference is the application of transmission gates and dynamic logic, which don't work so well in TTL, and have to be resolved with traditional gates. I would imagine they use active-low or passive-high signals in a number of places (other than just the outward-facing bus signals).

@TimWilliams I have indeed spent much time looking at the 6502 designs, and the great work done by Michael Steil, et al. Also the interactive 6502 net-level simulator. But the plan for this is really just to put together a simple processor based on the design proposed by Tanenbaum - and see if I can get a few instructions working. I just thought that I might as well try for binary compatability with 6502 opcodes.

@Greycon But the point was, you must know when you need only 8 bits out of 16 and then you also know you can enable a buffer to drive the unused 8 bits actively to logic low level.

@Justme fair enough, I see your point. I am also now looking at keeping the bus pulled high, and using inverted logic. I can easily use inverting buffers at each register, and the 74181 ALU will operate either active High or Active low logic.

I would debug one register that has connections for busses and control signals. Those connections can be on single-row rectangular headers. Then put that on a cheap PC board, and populate all the registers on boards. Then plug those boards into the breadboards. Ensure that the boards use flat components and you can easily put 4 of them per breadboard: two on each side of the divider.
If you are clever, you can have all the register sub-types on a common board that you then jumper-strap for a particular function. That will save a lot of error-prone wiring.
To put any fixed value on a bus without making this value be very slow to read, you'll need a constant register. E.g. to put zero on a bus, use a bus buffer with inputs connected to 0 (via resistors - this is TTL after all), and the output connected to the bus. This will be able to drive a 0 to the bus just as fast as any of the registers can drive their value.
Since you should be able to keep all the busses to within just a couple of breadboards, as long as you use sub-circuit PCBs, there is no need for line termination. The output impedance of the TTL drivers will damp the bus enough. On the PCBs you can leave optional series resistors between each output buffer and the bus. Those would be source termination that damps reflections. I would start with them being just wire links, and only increase their resistance away from 0Ω if you can show that it lets you run a higher clock rate. Otherwise - no point to it.

Hi, I cant seem to get @ to work with your Id :-) My plan was to get one or maybe 2 registers and the ALU working on breadboard, and with some external RAM. Then move to a wire-wrapped version. I've no experience with making PCBs. Although maybe I should learn.

@Greycon the @ convention only works when you're responding to a comment.  It's not necessary when you comment on an answer, since the answerer will be notified automatically.
